# What GPU should I get to accelerate my Linux desktop?

Tags: graphics-cards, linux

I have a Linux desktop machine that I use to work from home

Right now I have a cheap Nvidia GPU in there that is useless with its binary blob drivers that don't support video acceleration

I can get, for a reasonable price, an AMD FirePro W5000 GPU. Is that a good choice for stuff like YouTube acceleration, movie playback, desktop compositing and maybe even some light gaming?

Apparently it's almost identical to the GPU part of the APU in the original Xbox One (Durango)

Comment: I would avoid going for that firepro W5000, It's a ten year old workstation card. It's slower than most modern Integrated gpu's.   do you have a list of the other specs of your gpu and possible a budget?  It could help guide the recommendation.

Comment: When I get time I shall write down the spec of the entire machine. It is a very old low-power low-noise desktop for going under a TV, long before smart TVs and Chromecast came along.

Comment: Quick version: Athlon II X2 250, 6gb ddr3, 1tb Samsung sata flash 870 QVO. Enermax MODU82+, Gigabyte GA-MA785G-UD2H.

Comment: You will be fine with any currently supported AMD card, but nothing too new (like 1 month old) just to avoid bugs in brand new drivers. Even a modern Nvidia GPU has good proprietary drivers. I think you're just facing issues with a less common and out of date GPU (Like a GT 210?) that can't be supported by community/free drivers. A GT 1030 absolutely should support video acceleration in browsers and most applications on Linux, despite still being proprietary.

Comment: Except the GT 1030 being really expensive (€100 in Belgium). A GTX 750 would maybe be better (+=€50 second hand)

Comment: Ok, great, last question: where can I find them supported list for AMD open source drivers? And will they tell me how long a card will be supported for?